# Optimized Logic to find high score

Tags: php

Basically this is related to a squash application where we have 2 scores. One is from winner point of view and another from loser point of view.

eg.
Score1: 11-5,11-5,11-5    (Winner point of view)
Score2: 5-11, 5-11,5-11   (Loser point of view)

Now in my logic i want to find which is the winner score and which is the loser score.

I have written my logic in the below way and it does work. But i want to know if their is any other better/optimized way of writing this.

```
$high1 = 0;
$high2 = 0;

$score1 = "2-11,5-11,4-11,4-4";
$score2 = "11-2,11-5,11-4,4-4";

$score1Array = explode(",",$score1);

$size = sizeof($score1Array);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {

$checkscore1 = explode("-",$score1Array[$i]);


if($checkscore1[0] < $checkscore1[1]) {

    $high1++;

}else if($checkscore1[0] > $checkscore1[1]) {

    $high2++;

}


}

if($high1 > $high2) {

$winningScore = $score2;
$losingScore = $score1;
}else{

$winningScore = $score1;
$losingScore = $score2;
}

echo $winningscore;
echo $losingscore;
```

Comment: Why do you need the second string at all?

Comment: Not everyone of us is intimately familiar with squash scoring. So what are the criteria that put the score in one bin or the other? Just that most (or all?) numbers on the left are larger than the right or not?

Comment: Sorry Joey, i should have explained this earlier. Anyways here's how its done.

The game is played best of 5 sets.

If a player reaches the score 11 in any set then his opponents score should be less than 11.

If a player reaches the score more than 11, say 13, then the opponent's score should be 2 less than 13 that is 11.

The winner has to win atleast 3 games.

So,

    player1:  11 | 11| 13 | 11
    player2:   5 |  9| 15 |  3



So here player1 is the winner.

Comment: @sachleen, yes the second string is not required at all. Its just for reference. Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
function is_winning($score) {

  $split_scores = preg_split('/(-|,)/', $score);
  $wins = $losses = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < count($split_scores) / 2; $i += 2) {
    if($split_scores[$i] > $split_scores[$i + 1])
      $wins++;
    if($split_scores[$i] < $split_scores[$i + 1])
      $losses++;
  }

  return $wins > $losses;

}
```

Assuming `$score` is formatted as in your question. You can then use it like this:

```
$score1 = "2-11,5-11,4-11,4-4";
$score2 = "11-2,11-5,11-4,4-4";

if(is_winning($score1)) {
  $winning_score = $score1;
  $losing_score = $score2;
} else {
  $winning_score = $score2;
  $losing_score = $score1;
}

echo $winning_score;
echo $losing_score;
```

The idea is to split the score into an array where the even numbered indexes have the left score and the odd numbered indexes the right score. We then count the number of wins and the number of losses. If there's more wins then losses then we return true since the score was a winning score. If there's not more wins then losses we simply return false.

Comment: that was brilliant !!! Thanks. Your logic looks much concrete and optimized. Ticking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

for Winner point of view, all big score in left,otherwise in right. so u can just detect the first score.

```
$score1Array = explode(",",$score1);
$checkscore1 = explode("-",$score1Array[$i]);
if($checkscore1[0] < $checkscore1[1]) {
    echo $score2;
    echo $score1;
}else{
    echo $score1;
    echo $score2;
}
```

**Fix: above code is wrong,try this:**

```
$score1value = eval(str_replace(",","+",$score1));
$score2value = eval(str_replace(",","+",$score2));

if($score1value < $score2value) {
    echo $score2;
    echo $score1;
}else{
    echo $score1;
    echo $score2;
}
```

Comment: I think the "winner" will not be same everytime. No need to find the winner if we know it you know.

Comment: @xfx - what if the winner lost the first set?

Comment: Exactly...What if winner loses the first set. In squash there are total of 5 sets. So a min of wins required is 3 sets. I need to check every set to find out how many games each player won and lost.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$score1 = "2-11,5-11,4-11,4-4";
$score2 = "11-2,11-5,11-4,4-4";
$l = $r = 0;

$score1_sets_arr = explode(',', $score1);
foreach ($score1_sets_arr as $set_score) {
  $set_score_arr = explode('-', $set_score);
  if ($set_score_arr[0] > $set_score_arr[1]) {
    $l++;
  } else {
    $r++;
  }
}

if ($l > $r) {
  $winning_score = $score1;
  $losing_score  = $score2;
} else {
  $winning_score = $score2;
  $losing_score  = $score1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks air4x. That does work correctly. You have used foreach instead of for which doesnt require the size of the array. I think this is the most optimized solution. Any other suggestions ? I will wait for few hours and mark your answer as correct if nothing comes by.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
<?php
$high1 = 0;
$high2 = 0;

$score1 = "2-11,5-11,4-11,4-4";
$score2 = "11-2,11-5,11-4,4-4";

$explode = explode(",",$score1);


for($i=0;$i<  sizeof($explode);$i++){
    $explode2= explode("-", $explode[$i]);
    if($explode2[0] <= $explode2[1]){
        echo $explode2[0]."-";
        echo $explode2[1]." ";
    }

}
echo "<br />";
for($i=0;$i<  sizeof($explode);$i++){
    $explode2= explode("-", $explode[$i]);
    if($explode2[1] >= $explode2[0]){
        echo $explode2[1]."-";
        echo $explode2[0]." ";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: i didnt test your solution. But you are using the for loop twice which is not good for this small solution.